# "Reference the package directly from the project to resolve this issue."

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I'm trying to install a nuget package and I get the following error

> Restoring packages for C:\git...MyProject.csproj... NU1107: Version
>   conflict detected for Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs. Reference the package
>   directly from the project to resolve this issue.   MyProject ->
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask 1.4.1 ->
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs (>= 2.2.0)   MrProject ->
>   Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.6 -> Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs (=
>   2.1.0-beta4). Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'MyProject'. Time Elapsed: 00:00:00.5872740
>   ========== Finished ==========

I understand the issue, but I don't understand what "Reference the package directly from the project" means. Can someone explain?

Comment: Can you share your .csproj file content here?

Comment: [Related GitHub issue?](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-durable-extension/issues/36)

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 8):

> NU1107: Version conflict detected for Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.

Just as you know, this is a dependencies conflict issue. The one of dependency of package `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions 1.0.6` is **`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs (= 2.1.0-beta4)`**, but the dependencies of package `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask` need **`Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs (>= 2.2.0)`**. That is the version conflict.

> but I don't understand what "Reference the package directly from the
>   project" means. Can someone explain?

**That means you can reference the dll file directly not using NuGet**.

Details:

Download that nuget packages `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask.nupkg` from the [nuget.org](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask/), rename the file name to `.zip`, then unzip it. On the Solution explorer, select Dependencies->Add Dependencies->Browse->Select the dll file from the local folder.

**Besides**, Error message provides a common method to resolve this issue, but the best way to resolve this issue is update the package `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions` to **1.0.12** and above, which with a dependency **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs (>= 2.2.0 && < 2.3.0)**. This will compatible with package `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.DurableTask 1.4.1`.

Hope this helps.